# Angular 2 Typescript search button does not call method linked by ng-click

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to create a search function which uses text input to search for a corporation using a government http api (https://github.com/usagov/Corporate-Consumer-Contact-API-Documentation).

I have an html page called contact-list.component.html which has a button element on it that, when clicked, calls a function which exists in a component file (contact-list.component.ts). The function should use the string passed in to search using a service I am calling to find the corporation and output the results to an array I can bind to a table.

**contact-list.component.html**

```
       <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-2'>Enter Corporation Name:
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text"
            [(ngModel)] = 'searchString'/>
            <div><button class='btn btn-primary' ng-click="ContactListComponent.getResults(searchString)">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
```

**contact-list.component.ts**

```
    getResults(_searchString: string): any{

this._contactService.getContacts(this._searchString)
.subscribe(contacts => this.contacts = contacts,
     error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);

}
```

The problem is, when I input text and click the button, the console does not show any output and I do not appear to get any results back. In fact, when I replace the code in the getResults() method with

console.log("foo");

nothing displays in the console when I press F12. Any ideas on what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of a friend, I was able to fix the issue. My issue wasn't in any of the files I had previously listed. Rather, I was using  selectors in  too many component areas throughout my app. What fixed it was I changed my app.component.ts file's component selector property to app-root and instead called my  from the app.component.html. This is sort of a fundamental and was something I overlooked. Thanks to anyone who looked into my issue.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-click` is Angular 1's syntax. Use `(click)="..."`.

Besides, you don't need to (and must not) write `"ContactListComponent.getResults(searchString)"` but only `"getResults(searchString)"`, because you're already in the right component.

Also, you don't need to pass it `searchString` because it's already available in the component as `this.searchString`.

So, here's the correct syntax :

`(click)="getResults()"`

...and in your component :

```
getResults(): any{
    this._contactService
        .getContacts(this.searchString) // Already available thanks to [(ngModel)]="searchString" 
        .subscribe(...);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I made all the fixes you recommend, however, now I get javascript console errors when the button is clicked. The errors reads ::::

<<AppComponent.html:14 ERROR TypeError: _co.getResults is not a function
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (AppComponent.html:14)
    at handleEvent (core.es5.js:11997)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13458)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.es5.js:13046)
    at dispatchEvent (core.es5.js:8601)
    at core.es5.js:9212
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.es5.js:2651)>>

Comment: `getResults is not a function?` Did you write it at the right place in your component?

Comment: I wrote it after the constructor, inside the exported class called ContactListComponent.

Comment: UPDATE: Edge gives me a different error. It says "ERROR TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'getResults'". Chrome and Firefox give the same error mentioned earlier.